# Why did i get twice legend from matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

This is my figure:

[image]

This is my codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad 

mu = 0 
def fermions_integrand(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)*((np.log(1+np.exp(-x+mu))) + (1/(np.exp(x-mu)+1))*(x-mu))
def s_fermions(mu):
    return quad(fermions_integrand, 0, np.inf)

def bosons_integrand(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)*((-np.log(1-np.exp(-x+mu))) + (1/(np.exp(x-mu)-1))*(x-mu))
def s_bosons(mu):
    return quad(bosons_integrand, 0, np.inf)


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.title('Fermions Vs Bosons')
plt.xlabel(r'$\mu$')
plt.ylabel('s/g')
plt.plot(np.linspace(-10,10), [s_fermions(mu) for mu in np.linspace(-10,10)], 'b-', lw=3, color='red', label='Fermions')
plt.plot(np.linspace(-10,10), [s_bosons(mu) for mu in np.linspace(-10,10)], 'b-', lw=3, color='blue', label='Bosons')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I think code is so simple but why did i get this twice legends? How to solve this problem?

Further information: In actually, i have used this plot code already once time on another problem there was no problem (on Ubuntu) but for this i just move to OSX I'm not sure is it related to this problem or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `scipy.integrate.quad` returns the estimated integral value AND the estimate of the absolute error, as a tuple `(y,abserr)`

Then the two comprehension lists

```
[s_fermions(mu) for mu in np.linspace(-10,10)]
[s_bosons(mu) for mu in np.linspace(-10,10)]
```

are lists of couples of values, and you're plotting both the integrand and the absolute error (that is in fact very close to zero in the whole domain). Since you're plotting two lines at a time, you have two legend entries.

Simply add a trailing `[0]` in the return lines of `s_bosons` and of `s_fermions` to not plot the error.

Comment: As to why the code runs fine on Ubuntu, I can't say for sure. It could be because of a different `quad` or `matplotlib` version. If on Ubuntu you do not have the two horizontal lines, I'd guess you have a different version of `quad` on that machine.